# Minimum HARDWARE requirements for ODIN?

Tags: system-installation, hardware

I have a old 32bit-UEFI miniPC with ATOM CPU.

It has 2GB RAM, 30GB eMMC and 4x1440MHz CPU.

https://youtu.be/oizxGhz1DXU [image: CSL Narrow Box]

https://www.amazon.de/Mini-PC-lautlose-Silent-PC-Bluetooth/dp/B01EYN55JO

The white one has a X5-Z8300 Atom that should support 64bit code : https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/87383/intel-atom-x5-z8300-processor-2m-cache-up-to-1-84-ghz.html

How can I install elementary OS 6.x Odin with a 32bit-UEFI, and what PERFORMENCE can I expect with 2 GB RAM ?

Comment: Just discovered that my Vaio P use a Atom CPU not capable of executing 64bit code :-(

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sony_Vaio_P_series

So I removed them from this question.

Answer (score 1):

With the first system, you can't install it at all. eOS is a 64 bit OS. Those are limited to the 32 bit architecture. You'll need a 32 bit OS.

With the second system, you can install it - but your performance will be pretty poor.

These are the *minimum* requirements for the *current* version of eOS:

- Recent Intel i3 or comparable dual-core 64-bit processor
- 4 GB of system memory (RAM)
- Solid state drive (SSD) with 15 GB of free space
- Internet access
- 1024×768 display

You meet most of the requirements, but you do not meet the minimum RAM requirements. The device you linked only has 2 GB of RAM, or half of the minimum recommended amount. The next version will have *at least* the same minimum requirements.

It'll probably run, but it won't be very fast. You will be very disappointed with the performance.

So, what can you do?

For the first systems, you can search [DistroWatch](https://distrowatch.com/search.php) for 32 bit systems.

For the second system, and for the first, you can use [this handy list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light-weight_Linux_distribution) of lightweight Linux distros.

Don't fret, however. If you follow those two links, there are many choices for you to pick from. It isn't too hard to find a distro that works well and suits your needs, nor is it all that challenging to make them aesthetically pleasing.

They (the Linux community, not eOS) haven't stopped developing for 32 bit, but it has slowed because there are fewer people to test on 32 bit hardware. eOS has made the decision to not support 32 bit computers at all.

Comment: Looks like I will have to use Bodhi Linux for my old Vaio P pocketPC :-(

Comment: @MEX Bodhi isn't bad. You might also like MX Linux. You can test out a bunch of them right here: https://distrotest.net/index.php

Comment: That still leaves the problem unsolved HOW do I prepare a USB stick which can boot Odin on my CSL Narrow Box with its 32bitUEFI and HOW to install Odin on this miniPC so that it boots with a 32bitUEFI into a 64bit kernel !

Comment: You can't install Odin on a 32 bit system. It doesn't have anywhere near the right software - you'd need far more than a 32 bit kernel. As for how you prepare a USB stick, you use something like [Balena Etcher](https://www.balena.io/etcher/).

Comment: Didnt you READ that its a 64bit system with a 32bit UEFI ?

Comment: You've edited your post so many times that I now have no idea what you have. Either way, none of your systems meet the minimum recommended requirements for the *current* version and newer versions *never* have lower requirements. So, even if you do get it installed, you're not going to get satisfactory performance. Your CPUs don't compare to an i3, either. The i3 is in the 3.5 to 4.0 GHz range. eOS will not run well on your hardware. Pick a different distro, or be prepared for it to run very slowly. You have half the recommended RAM.

Comment: And, finally, your 32 bit UEFI quite probably means you can't install 64 bit OSes, unless you manage to get E2B+agFM to work. The OEM only included 32 bit UEFI in all but the rarest of cases with these. You're wasting your time trying to get eOS to work in this situation. Pick a different distro.